# Problem with making plot using Plots in Jupyternotebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, julia-plots

When I am trying to make plot in Julia REPL it is possible, but when I use Jupyternotebook for even make the basic plot from Julia documentation

```
using Plots
x = 1:10; y = rand(10); # These are the plotting data
plot(x, y)
```

I see error:

```
SystemError: opening file "C:\\Users\\Kasia\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\jl_rgpMDkxG5u.svg": No such file or directory
```

And I have no idea what should I do.

I tried to remove Plots and add it again. Also updating Plots and GR. I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Please provide `versioninfo()`, `Pkg.status("Plots")`, `Pkg.status("GR")`, `Pkg.status("IJulia")`. Do you also see the error when you run `pyplot()` before the `plot` command?

Comment: Thanks, the jupyter update solved the issue

Comment: Still please provide the version numbers that did not work so maybe others have a chance to know

Comment: Well, I guess I cannot get them now, after update? But I installed jupyternotebook sth like month or two ago, and that time I had the most actual version and didn't have any problems with making plots.

Comment: In that case let's close this question as it is hardly useful to anyone else :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jupyter update solved the issue